# subset xts zoo to obtain only one month

Tags: r, subset, xts, zoo

I have a monthly xts/zoo timeseries object and I would like to subset this so that I obtain only the value for the monthy of November. So for each year, I want only the month of November.  This is the object (it is downloaded):

```
library(quantmod)
indPro<-getSymbols('INDPRO', src="FRED", auto.assign=FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is what the data looks like:

```
           INDPRO
1919-01-01 5.0346
1919-02-01 4.8121
1919-03-01 4.6730
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
indPro[.indexmon(indPro) == 10,]
```

0 is Jan, 1, is Feb, ... 11 is December.

You have also find it useful to know about:

```
.indexyear
.indexday
.indexweek
.indexhour
.indexmin
.indexsec
```

Take a look at the help for `?.indexsec` for more.

Comment: Great answer, didn't know about this function!

Answer (score 0):

What does your data look like?

assuming your data looks somewhat like: 
df$Date = c(10-01-2015 12:22:00, etc.)

I've used `dplyr` and `zoo` in the past - try `df <- df %>% filter(month(Date) == 11)`

Comment: I provided the data above, it can be downloaded using the package quantmod. The date is available this way:dates <-index(INDPRO.stdres1). It looks like this: 2010-04-01